# Update data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to update my data in database. I tried to update the `Name` and `Order` in the database. However, I can't update my database. The error is

> DbEntityValidationException was unhandled by user code.

How can I solve this?

The following code is my controller

```
public ActionResult Update(Person[] People)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < People.Length; i++)
    {
        Person person = db.Persons.Find(People[i].ID);
        person.Order = People[i].Order;
        person.Name = People[i].Name;
        db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }


    return Json(new { JsonResult = "NICE" });
}
```

Comment: what error occurred?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: The error tells you exactly why it's not working. If you don't understand the error, read [ask] and research it, then [edit] your question to include both the error and what you learned from your research.

Comment: You will need to look into the internal exceptions to see what went wrong, that Exception acts more like a wrapper.

Comment: Flagged as duplicate too, is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment this exception is more like a wrapper, you could loop through it in your error handler pulling out all of the validation errors

Something like this

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
DbEntityValidationException validationException = (DbEntityValidationException)exception;
foreach (var e in validationException.EntityValidationErrors)
{
    foreach (var err in e.ValidationErrors)
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"Validation Error:{err.ErrorMessage}, Property: {err.PropertyName}");
    }
}
```